# Big ( 1GB) JSON data handling in Tableau

Tags: json, twitter, datasource, tableau-api, bigdata

I am working with a large twitter dataset in the form of a JSON file. When I try to import that into Tableau, there is an error and the upload fails on the account of data upload limit of 128 MB.

Due to which I need to shrink the dataset to bring it to 128MB thereby reducing the effectiveness of the analysis.

**What is the best way to upload and handle large JSON data in tableau?** 
Do I need to use an external tool for it?
 Can we use AWS products to handle the same? Please advise!

Comment: what version of Tableau are you using, and where are you uploading data to?  Tableau should not have any limits to the size of data you can use (unless they place them on a free or public version). 128 MB is rather small

Comment: I'm using tableau Desktop 10.3 I'm using json file upload for this. Please let me know if there is any other info that I can add that may help you answer my question

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I'm not able to replicate you're error.  Would you be able to provide a full screenshot of the error when it is generated?

Comment: Are you using the 32-bit version of Tableau?

Comment: @SamM I was using 64 bit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can find in unofficial documents online, Tableau does indeed have a 128 MB limit on JSON file size. You have several options.

- Split the JSON files into multiple files and union them in your data source (https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/examples_json.html#Union)
- Use a tool to convert the JSON to csv or Excel (Google for JSON to csv converter)
- Load the JSON into a database, such as MySql and use the MySql as the data source

You may want to consider posting in the Ideas section of the Tableau Community pages and add a suggestion for allowing larger JSON files. This will bring it to the attention of the broader Tableau community and product management.

Comment: I think your second option is the most optimal, assuming the data doesn't require complex queries to retrieve it, in which case you want the 3rd option. If you compare JSON and CSV file sizes, the CSV file will be smaller.